# Required argument for compiled program?

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there any way to do required argument for crystal program?
For example

```
./myprog ~/Music -r
```

Instead of

```
./myprog -d ~/Music -r
```

So my program wont run if there's no [directory] argument. Right now using "option_parser" and can only do -arguments.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to create required arguments using `option_parser`, but you can parse arguments and throw an error or exit if there is no argument passed you expect:

```
require "option_parser"

directory = nil

parser = OptionParser.new
parser.on("-d DIR", "Directory [required]") do |d|
  directory = d
end
parser.parse ARGV

if directory.nil?
  # directory argument was not set
  # print help and exit
  puts parser
  exit 1
else
  # ...
end
```